# to apply a thing

Tags: meaning

I know the meaning of this verb. But could anyone help me to understand the meaning in the context of this sentence:

> The oil-torch had been applied to the engine, and it rolled forth,
>   belching flames.I was hanging on for dear life, now and then catching sight of the driver urging his plunging horses onward like a charioteer in a modern Ben Hur race. The tender with Craig and McCormick was lost in the clouds of smoke and sparks that trailed behind us.

I want to translate that phrase, but i dont understand the action of "applying" in this case. The fire engine was pulled by horses and was hurrying to a place of fire in the night. I took it from a story of the year of 1912.
I would appriciate your help

Comment: _Apply_ `X` _to_ `Y` requires a knowledge of the normal use of X. How does one use an oil-torch? I would imagine to light a fire. Is there a fire on the engine? It is belching flames. Where did they come from?

Comment: So that means that they just lighted an oil-torch on the engine? Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Or they lit the engine with the oil-torch. Remember that the engine was not a truck but a horse-drawn water pump with a steam engine.

Comment: So you mean "to roll forth" it refers to the engine not to the oil-torch?

Comment: That would be my guess. But I don't know. There's no context except what I can imagine from one sentence. Which is practically anything if I'm imaginative.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you to take your time. Do you think would be useful to add some conext to my question?